# How can I change my domain registrar in Google Apps?

Tags: google, domain

I had domainA (primary) that was registered under Go Daddy and now it has been moved to a new registrar. Unfortunately, my Google Apps control panel still shows Go Daddy as my primary domain registrar and I am not given any option to change it. I contacted Go Daddy support and they were not able to help.

Any ideas on how this can be solved?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it doesn't matter to Google Apps _which_ domain registrar you are with. Its a matter of making sure the MX records at your new registrar are still pointing to the [correct servers](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33915)

Answer (score 1):

You moved registrar from GoDaddy to NEW Registrar.

So you need to make sure your MX records at your NEW Registrar are correctly setup.
http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33352&topic=2683820&ctx=topic

This MX records might take up to 72 hours to take effect, you can test it whether your setup is good or not by using the MX Tool to see what is the error.
https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx/

You might want to setup SPF TXT:
http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33786&topic=2759192&ctx=topic

And then your CNAME:
http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47283

I think you should be fine after these. Theoretically, you just need to tell your NEW Registrar where this domain should be pointed to.